# Factorial kriging in Python

Tags: python

Is there any python Factorial Kriging library ?
I found some in R, however, I would like to keep it in Python.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What features would you need exactly from such a library?

Comment: Factorial Kriging and Automatic Factorial Kriging

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one:
https://github.com/bsmurphy/PyKrige

From the website:

> The code supports 2D and 3D ordinary and universal kriging. Standard variogram models (linear, power, spherical, gaussian, exponential) are built in, but custom variogram models can also be used. The 2D universal kriging code currently supports regional-linear, point-logarithmic, and external drift terms, while the 3D universal kriging code supports a regional-linear drift term in all three spatial dimensions. Both universal kriging classes also support generic 'specified' and 'functional' drift capabilities. With the 'specified' drift capability, the user may manually specify the values of the drift(s) at each data point and all grid points. With the 'functional' drift capability, the user may provide callable function(s) of the spatial coordinates that define the drift(s). The package includes a module that contains functions that should be useful in working with ASCII grid files (*.asc).

Comment: Hi David:
Thanks for your response.
I am looking specifically for Factorial Kriging. I checked PyKrige, it doesn’t seem to contain it.
This geostatistical technique is used in signal analysis and geophysical data signal filtering.
R package (RGeostats - FKA): http://rgeostats.free.fr/doc/FKA.html
I would prefer keeping my work in Python